# What is the mechanism of this class? (JSON Parsing)

Tags: java, json, hashmap, gson

I am trying to understand this short file but I can't wrap my head around it. Could you clarify its use please? I think its organising a JSON file?

```
package net.stackoverflow;

import com.google.gson.JsonObject;
import com.google.gson.JsonParser;

public class Program {
  public String contents;

  public String name;

  public boolean visible;

  public String fileHeader;

  public Program() {
    this.fileHeader = "";
    this.name = "";
    this.visible = false;
    this.contents = "";
  }

  public Program(String metaJson) {
    JsonParser parse = new JsonParser();
    JsonObject entry = parse.parse(metaJson).getAsJsonObject();
    this.fileHeader = entry.get("Filename").getAsString();
    this.name = entry.get("displayName").getAsString();
    this.visible = !entry.get("hidden").getAsBoolean();
    this.contents = entry.get("data").getAsString();
  }
}
```

Note that this class is using the GSON lib.
Furthermore, it is used in a hash map in another class in the following way:

```
public HashMap<String, theclassIdontget> directory;
```

I don't know if this info helps but it can't be too much...
Thank you for your help!

Comment: It's `parse.parse(metaJson)` the given JSON to extract those 4 fields.

Comment: Oh that's it?
How does it save it tho?
And final question, what does the  public Program() method do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you mentioned on the title this class is parsing a json string.

the following part of the class is where the member variables are being declared:

```
public String contents;
public String name;
public boolean visible;
public String fileHeader;
```

This is the class constructor which initializes the member variables with default values:

```
 public Program() {
  this.fileHeader = "";
  this.name = "";
  this.visible = false;
  this.contents = "";
}
```

here is a second constructor that takes a string( that is the json content ), parses the json using a JsonParser object ( retrieves the requested properties and stores those values in the member variable ).

```
public Program(String metaJson) {
  JsonParser parse = new JsonParser();
  JsonObject entry = parse.parse(metaJson).getAsJsonObject();
  this.fileHeader = entry.get("Filename").getAsString();
  this.name = entry.get("displayName").getAsString();
  this.visible = !entry.get("hidden").getAsBoolean();
  this.contents = entry.get("data").getAsString();
}
```

So when you create a `Program` object with the `Program( string json )` constructor such as:

```
Program myProgram = Program( jsonString )
```

you can access the json property values by doing the following:

```
myProgram.name 
myProgram.contents
```